# Left banner background improperly styled, while using tables

Tags: html, css

I have a logo on the top left corner, but the coloured banner envelops the logo (by a 1px). I want the colour to ONLY start below the logo. Here is my plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/XgnGewkSImk4Me6irfBh/preview

Whatever I do, it will either envelop the logo (1px) OR the banner will be right beside the logo. Tried working on this for an hour to no avail :/

(I have to use tables in this particular case)

EDIT: The banner has to grow by itself (no fixed height) with the text that appears, just in case you were wondering. For example, if there are 5 paragraphs, then it means the banner has to grow just as much.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-nbsp-mode: space;
  -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;
  margin: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 29px;
}
.float_left {
  float: left;
}
.float_right {
  float: right;
}
.clear_float {
  clear: both;
}
.display_none {
  display: none;
}
.margin_auto {
  margin: auto !important;
}
#main_table {
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.banner_table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.text_table {
  width: 700px;
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.td_two {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.td_three {
  width: 107px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 107px;
  height: 79px;
}
.bgbanner {
  /*      background-color:#E7E7E7;*/
  background-color: black;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 107px;
}
#space {
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.blue_bgbanner {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #093981;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  ;
}
.gif {
  width: 299px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.width_12 {
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<table class="main_table margin_auto">
  <tr>
    <td class="bgbanner">
      <table class="banner_table">
        <tr>
          <td class="td_three">
            <img src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/1635/sfi/free_16354477.jpg" class="logo" alt="" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="space">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="width_12">
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class="text_table">
        <tr>
          <td class="blue_bgbanner clear_float"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="clear_float">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum ut ultricies commodo purus mattis egestas. Morbi sed diam in augue posuere convallis. Phasellus ac efficitur metus, in imperdiet eros. Nulla facilisi. Duis ultricies mattis sapien. Aliquam lacinia, arcu eu imperdiet cursus, dui risus porttitor
              lacus, at placerat magna eros vel massa. Vivamus sit amet dictum purus. Maecenas dictum augue eu velit pharetra congue. Curabitur suscipit ante sed turpis semper lacinia. Mauris luctus vel urna sed elementum. Curabitur ut risus nibh. Praesent
              lectus purus, congue et luctus sit amet, congue eu massa. Vestibulum dolor lorem, elementum sed dui in, hendrerit commodo orci. Cras eu urna nec odio rutrum suscipit. Donec sit amet lorem scelerisque, venenatis est eu, porta enim. Nam quam
              leo, sollicitudin at nunc id, posuere molestie arcu
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why do you *have* to use tables?

Comment: @misterManSam You know how it is at work. You do what they ask lol.

Comment: and here is [an updated version of fight the power table layout](http://jsbin.com/zixilu/2/edit). Interested? A lot cleaner.

Comment: @misterManSam I applied this to see exactly how it would look. I understand that you applied the height attribute. The solution per se is not bad in any way, but I truly am looking for having the banner expand by itself.

Comment: You mean expand to the bottom? [like this example](http://jsbin.com/zixilu/2/edit)

Comment: or expand with content but with a min-height like [this example](http://jsbin.com/zixilu/3/edit) ?

Comment: @misterManSam lol, so many examples from varied pps lol. Lemme check them all out. I tried the first one (it was good), will see yours you added as well. I will post back when I have done so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Two Examples

### 1 - Without changing HTML

Without changing layout, just remove the default padding from the td:

```
td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Gives us this:

[image: Screenshot]

I also added `border-collapse: collapse` and removed the height property on the image.

Here is your new demo:

```css
td {
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-nbsp-mode: space;
  -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;
  margin: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 29px;
}
.float_left {
  float: left;
}
.float_right {
  float: right;
}
.clear_float {
  clear: both;
}
.display_none {
  display: none;
}
.margin_auto {
  margin: auto !important;
}
#main_table {
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.banner_table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.text_table {
  width: 700px;
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.td_two {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.td_three {
  width: 107px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 107px;
}
.bgbanner {
  /*      background-color:#E7E7E7;*/
  background-color: black;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 107px;
}
#space {
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.blue_bgbanner {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #093981;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  ;
}
.gif {
  width: 299px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.width_12 {
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<table class="main_table margin_auto">
  <tr>
    <td class="bgbanner">
      <table class="banner_table">
        <tr>
          <td class="td_three">
            <img src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/1635/sfi/free_16354477.jpg" class="logo" alt="" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="space">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="width_12">
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class="text_table">
        <tr>
          <td class="blue_bgbanner clear_float"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="clear_float">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum ut ultricies commodo purus mattis egestas. Morbi sed diam in augue posuere convallis. Phasellus ac efficitur metus, in imperdiet eros. Nulla facilisi. Duis ultricies mattis sapien. Aliquam lacinia, arcu eu imperdiet cursus, dui risus porttitor
              lacus, at placerat magna eros vel massa. Vivamus sit amet dictum purus. Maecenas dictum augue eu velit pharetra congue. Curabitur suscipit ante sed turpis semper lacinia. Mauris luctus vel urna sed elementum. Curabitur ut risus nibh. Praesent
              lectus purus, congue et luctus sit amet, congue eu massa. Vestibulum dolor lorem, elementum sed dui in, hendrerit commodo orci. Cras eu urna nec odio rutrum suscipit. Donec sit amet lorem scelerisque, venenatis est eu, porta enim. Nam quam
              leo, sollicitudin at nunc id, posuere molestie arcu
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### 2 - Simplified. Less table elements, more CSS.

Now, as discussed in the comments, we can treat the tables more like divs and style them in the same way. As the table requirement seems arbitrary, maybe this is a good compromise?

- Create two tables, side-by-side.
- Each table is given the CSS property `display: inline-table` so they line up
- The left table is given a single td to fill with content
- The right table is given a thead with a single th for the header content and a tbody with a single td for the main content body.
- The height of the two tables can be 100% of the page height, if desired.

The left table in this example has `min-height: 500px`, and will expand once content reaches the 500px threshold.

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrap {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.left {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  background: #000;
  min-height: 500px;
}
.left img {
    width: 100%;
}
.right {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

/*Treat it like a div*/
.right .header {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

/*Treat it like a div*/
.right .content {
  padding: 20px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <table class="left">
    <tr>
      <td>        
        
        <img src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/1635/sfi/free_16354477.jpg">      
      
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <table class="right">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="header">          
          
          Header content         
          
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="content">      
          
          Give me more content!        

        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `border-collapse` appears to make things a bit easier to style, but overall, it is a lot of work to get a relatively simple layout.  My solution is slightly different, but I think yours is a bit more concise.  I don't think the floats are necessary, but I did not check.

Comment: Like the OP said, sometimes you work with what you are given!  We can look to a brighter future with CSS3! All the best!

Comment: @misterManSam, I looked at all the work from both you and Marc. The first two you had showed me earlier (in the comment section) were not what I was referring to - and thus did not work as expected. As for the third one you had shown (the one with the collapse) worked great, without affecting the space between the image and the border

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it.  It is slightly complex with the nested tables.

I noticed that your logo image was being distorted, so my solution was based on 
letting the image take on the specified width of 107px and then expand vertically.

To get the background color right, you need to apply the background color to the 
table cell below the table and not to the table itself nor to the cell containing
the nested table.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-nbsp-mode: space;
  -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;
  margin: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 29px;
}
.float_left {
  float: left;
}
.float_right {
  float: right;
}
.clear_float {
  clear: both;
}
.display_none {
  display: none;
}
.margin_auto {
  margin: auto !important;
}
#main_table {
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.banner_table {
  width: 107px;
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  height: inherit;
}
.text_table {
  width: 700px;
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.td_two {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.td_three {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.td_three img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 107px;
  height: 79px;
}
.bgbanner {
  /*  background-color:#E7E7E7;*/
  background-color: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 107px;
  height: 100%;
}
#space {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
.blue_bgbanner {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #093981;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  ;
}
.gif {
  width: 299px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.width_12 {
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<table class="main_table margin_auto">
  <tr>
    <td class="bgbanner">
      <table class="banner_table">
        <tr>
          <td class="td_three">
            <img src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/1635/sfi/free_16354477.jpg" class="logo" alt="" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="space">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="width_12">
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class="text_table">
        <tr>
          <td class="blue_bgbanner clear_float"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="clear_float">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum ut ultricies commodo purus mattis egestas. Morbi sed diam in augue posuere convallis. Phasellus ac efficitur metus, in imperdiet eros. Nulla facilisi. Duis ultricies mattis sapien. Aliquam lacinia, arcu eu imperdiet cursus, dui risus porttitor
              lacus, at placerat magna eros vel massa. Vivamus sit amet dictum purus. Maecenas dictum augue eu velit pharetra congue. Curabitur suscipit ante sed turpis semper lacinia. Mauris luctus vel urna sed elementum. Curabitur ut risus nibh. Praesent
              lectus purus, congue et luctus sit amet, congue eu massa. Vestibulum dolor lorem, elementum sed dui in, hendrerit commodo orci. Cras eu urna nec odio rutrum suscipit. Donec sit amet lorem scelerisque, venenatis est eu, porta enim. Nam quam
              leo, sollicitudin at nunc id, posuere molestie arcu
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I really do love your approach. It is very simple, and I clearly spent too much time at the wrong place within my code lol. Nicely done. I will save the code in case I need it in the future (I would not be surprised!). I looked at both misterManSam's code and yours, and there are a few little differences that make his code slightly better in terms of stylizing some elements. However, your code is clearly well thought out. There is nothing wrong with it in any way. I do appreciate having it here on stackoverflow. Btw, concerning the image, I replaced the real image due to copyright issues.